# Solve $y' + \frac{1}{4}y''^2 = xy''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$y' + \frac{1}{4}y''^2 = xy''$$

**My Attempt**

take $p = y'$ and $p' = y''$ then $$p+\frac{1}{4}p'^2 = xp' \rightarrow p'^2-4xp'+4p=0$$

Use the quadratic to get:

$$p' = \frac{4x \pm\sqrt{16x^2-16p}}{2} \rightarrow 2x \pm 2\sqrt{x^2-p}$$

I am not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: Constant y is a solution, you could also try the form $x^n$ for y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
p=xp'-\frac14p'^2
$$
is a nice Clairaut DE. The linear solution family is
$$
p=Cx-\frac14C^2
$$
which then integrates to
$$
y(x)=\frac12Cx^2-\frac14C^2x+D.
$$
Note that a solution can be composed of up to 3 segments if one switches solutions when tangential to the singular solution/envelope.